# Derivative of complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I intend to compute the $k_{x}-$gradiente of the following function,
$$\phi=\arctan\left(\frac{m}{k_{x}-isk_{y}}\right)$$
where $m\in\mathbb{R}$ and $s=\pm1$. How can I do this?
I think maybe I should use the chain rule where I could start the calculation from,
$$\partial_{x}\phi=\frac{d\phi}{dz}\frac{dz}{dk_{x}}$$
where $z=\dfrac{m}{k_{x}-isk_{y}}=m\dfrac{k_{x}+isk_{y}}{k_{x}^2+(sk_{y})^2}$. But I'm not sure if this is correct.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $\;k_x\;$ ? A function of $\;x\;$ ?

Comment: $k_{x}$ and $k_{y}$ can be treated as independents variables. One can think of $k_{x}\to x$ and $k_{y}\to y$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thus applying the Chain Rule for the *variable* $\;k_x\;$:

$$\phi_{k_x}=\frac{-m}{(k_x-isk_y)^2}\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{m^2}{(k_x-isk_y)^2}}=-\frac m{(k_x-isk_y)^2+m^2}$$

Comment: Please, how to determine $Re(\phi)$?

Comment: Remember that $$\arctan z=\frac1{2i}\log\frac{i-z}{i+z}$$